# Is order matter when writing the roots of a quadratic equation?

Tags: quadratics

Equation:

> $x^2-x-6=0$

The two roots of this equation are $3$ and $-2$. When writing the answer can I also write it as $-2, 3$ or do I have to maintain a certain order?

Comment: Ordering elements of a set doesn't matter.

Comment: Saying it either way, if you mean the *set* of zeroes of the equation, then it makes no difference.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I was answering a multiple answer question which asked to determine the roots of the equation. One of the options was 3, -2 and one of the other option was -2, 3. Please note that the options didn't have any opening or closing second bracket {}. Does this make any difference, or is it a problem with the question?

Comment: $\{a,b,c\}=\{a,c,b\}=\{b,c,a\}=...\}

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I understand your first comment. What I wanted to know is do we always write the roots of the equation as elements of a set? can we write the roots in a way where the order is matter?

Comment: The order of the roots makes no difference. In fact, I can hardly believe what you say about the multiple-choice question. Are you sure the second one wasn't $\{2,-3\}$?

Comment: @TonyK I'm sure. There are four options in total. A. {2, 3} B. {-3, -2} C. {3, -2} D. {-2, 3}. It could be a printing mistake, but there's no way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question offers the two choices you gave us in a comment, $-2, 3$ and $3, -2$, then the question is wrong. Either answer is correct. Perhaps one of the suggested answers should have had  the signs the other way   $2, -3$ ( not the order the other way). Then they might be looking for a particular error you might have made.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the roots should not matter, the solutions {-2,3} still conveys the same meaning as {3, -2}. Edit: some people may prefer you to order your solution from   the least greatest to greatest value for ease of marking (e.g. -2 then 3), but mathematically, it makes no difference.

Comment: Is there any way to write the roots where the order is matter or is it the only way to do it?